# Highchart bubble chart causing issue with different number of bubbles it takes different height

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there any solution that We can provide hight only for the plot area in which  I have shown background image.

Comment: You are going to need to provide a little more information...

Answer (score 0):

You can define only height of entire container, not plotarea.